# how to trace a shell script running the background?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have run a script like this:

```
script.sh > terminal.txt 2>&1 &
```

It contains long loops.

how can I trace (which process with what name and what id was created) that script and kill the process to terminate that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script)

Comment: I was responding to "how can I trace that script".

Comment: But doesn't `bash -x` from the question I linked help? I assume it would give you the info, what's started. I don't know about the PIDs though.

Comment: OK, glad you solved your problem, but word of advice for the future - many-**standalone**-questions-in-one post are forbidden, and mods are encouraged to pick one question at random, and delete the rest. You can then post the deleted parts as new questions. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post. When you have several **standalone** questions, take the time to make a separate post for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though,  @hek2mgl 's answer was great help and paved the way to solution, but the actual solution is a bit different:

Type `fg` in the terminal.

Then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Type `fg` in the terminal. Then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

See: [Job Control Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html)

Comment: I have seen a number like this: `[1] 25647` but how to kill it. I have already used `pkill -f 25647` and its still running

Comment: also Ctrl+c is not giving any response

Comment: `pkill` takes a process *name* as argument, not a pid. Use `kill -9 25647` in that case. If you are in the same shell where you started the process you can also issue `kill -9 %1`. Bash will translate  `%1` to the corresponding pid.